# Why isn't my data getting inserted into a MySQL database from my Python Flask application?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL database from a register form in my Flask web application, but upon submission it does not get entered into the database.

I have used the database access commands in a separate class in Python, but in the past I have also tried to incorporate them in the 'app.py' file.

This is a dictionary for the details of the DB:

```
app.config['dbconfig'] = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'user': 'adminu', 'password': 'password', 'database': 'app_uni'}
```

This is my method to display the registration form and subsequently store input data into the DB.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        with UseDB(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
            _SQL = '''insert into student_users(username, email,      password, counsellor, grade, st_name)(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)'''
        cursor.execute(_SQL, (form.username.data, form.email.data,   form.password.data, form.counsellor.data, form.grade.data,    form.st_name.data))
        flash('You are now registered and can log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('/about'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)`
```

Here is  the code for the context management:

```
import mysql.connector

class UseDB:

    def __init__(self, config: dict):
        self.configuration = config

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self.configuration)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
```

I am trying to get the program to redirect me to the about page after registration. However, I am not redirected to any webpage and my DB is not getting updated. I also don't receive any error messages, so I think it might be a logical error.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong, and give me a hint on how to go forward?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried looking at using sqlalchemy?

Comment: No, I haven't thought about using SQLAlchemy. But I am using mysql.connector provided by Oracle right now. I would prefer if you could hint at a problem in the current code so that I can get a better grip on mysqlconnector. :)

Comment: also you are not redirected because url_for actually accepts a name of the function of your endpoint instead of the url itself. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.url_for

Comment: can you try putting the cursor.execute() within the `with` statement

Comment: Hi wasp8898, thanks for your response. I did try putting cursor.execute() in the with block, but there were no changes. Also, can you please clarify your suggestion on the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the redirect isn't happening, but I suspect the reason your database isn't being updated is because you're executing the SQL outside of the with block. You have:

```py
with UseDB(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
    _SQL = '''insert into student_users(username, email, password, counsellor, grade, st_name)(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)'''
cursor.execute(_SQL, (form.username.data, form.email.data, form.password.data, form.counsellor.data, form.grade.data, form.st_name.data))
```

Because you call `cursor.execute` outside of the with-block, `UseDB.__exit__` has already been called and the connection to the database is closed. I think what you want is

```py
with UseDB(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
    _SQL = '''insert into student_users(username, email, password, counsellor, grade, st_name)(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)'''
    cursor.execute(_SQL, (form.username.data, form.email.data, form.password.data, form.counsellor.data, form.grade.data, form.st_name.data))
```

If `cursor.execute` is throwing an exception because the connection is closed, that might also explain why the redirect isn't happening.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. I have tried putting the cursor.execute statement inside the with block, but there haven't been any changes. The database still doesn't update...

Comment: It looks like you may also have an error in the SQL statement (at least as far as I'm familiar with SQL). Are you missing the `VALUES` keyword? Should it be `INSERT INTO student_users (...) VALUES (...)`? Are you getting any errors in your logs that can share?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do for the url_for function to redirect. It accepts the function name as the argument instead of the url.

```
@app.route('/about', methods=['GET'])
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        with UseDB(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
            _SQL = '''insert into student_users(username, email,      password, counsellor, grade, st_name)(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)'''
            cursor.execute(_SQL, (form.username.data, form.email.data,   form.password.data, form.counsellor.data, form.grade.data,    form.st_name.data))
        flash('You are now registered and can log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('about'))  # instead of the url, use the function name of /about
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Hello wasp8898, I have tried implementing your suggestion, but it still does not re-direct me to the about page. Could this just be a glitch of some sort?

Comment: Also, am I correct to assume that it is @api.route was a typo?

Comment: @MathTakingOvertheWorld yea its a typo, just edited the answer. I am not sure why you are not getting redirected, are you sure there are no errors on the console? or anywhere?

Comment: Also, don't change the code on your question, because now the answer below is irrelevant and the comments too.

Comment: This shows up on my console:                                                                     127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2019 22:12:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2019 22:12:02] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2019 22:12:30] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
So it does go into the post request, and by right it should execute the 'if' statement. Do you think I might be missing a particular package?